# How to compare two data frame and return result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frame, I want to compare each value and return a result,
if the value from 'dis' is greater than 'para' the result is 1, else is 0, and count how many 1 and 0:

```
data_6

  dis
1  409.31
2  193.34
3  286.83
4  439.95
5  217.51
6  248.91
7  427.44
```

and

```
data_11
 para
0  223.46
1   92.26
2   66.86
3   52.14
4   69.55
5   94.20
6  129.96
7  734.35
```

I try concat, but it give me error:

```
data_12['result'] = np.where(data_12['dis'] > data_12['para'],'1','0')
```

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I expected the new data_12 and data_result table will be:

```
   dis         para      result
1  409.31     315.72       1
2  193.34     159.12       1
3  286.83     119.00       1
4  439.95     121.69       1
5  217.51     163.75       1
6  248.91     224.16       1
7  734.35     427.44       0

Another result table: 
1   0 
6   1
```

Comment: `np.where(data_12['dis'].astype(float) > data_12['para'].astype(float),'1','0')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dis':[1,1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'para':[0,2,2,3]})

data_12 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
data_12['result'] = np.where(data_12['dis']>data_12['para'], 1,0)
```

and you get:

```
   dis  para  result
0    1     0       1
1    1     2       0
2    2     2       0
3    3     3       0
```

To count the occurrences of 0's and 1's:

```
data_result = data_12['result'].value_counts()
```

and you get:

```
0    3
1    1
```

As mentioned by anky_91, if values in your dataframes are strings, you first need to convert them to float and then do the rest as in my code.

Comment: NameError: name 'dftot' is not defined

Comment: Run the code. Note that in your question values in `data_11` are different from those in column `para` in dataframe `data_12`. I assume this is a typo.